# Why is True Assigned to a Variable?

Tags: python, boolean

This function checks whether a string contains any lowercase characters and returns `True` if so:

```
def any_lowercase(s):
    flag = False
    for c in s:
        flag = flag or c.islower()
    return flag
```

I cannot understand the line `flag = flag or c.islower()`. Let's check whether a string "cAR" has got any lowercase characters. The initial value of `flag` is `False`. The first character is "c", and the program gets to that line I mentioned earlier. If we substitute the values, we get `flag = False or True`. What does that mean? Why is `True` assigned to the variable and not `False`?

Comment: The `or` operator will produce `True` if either or both operands are `True`.   `True or False` is `True`.  That's what `or` does.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_disjunction_(OR)

Comment: this seems like a very basic question, `False or True` will produce `True`. I recommend you to read about `truth table` if you haven't

Comment: This is the normal behaviour of the boolean `or`... You would probably benefit much from reading some good comprehensive tutorial (see a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: (How do you get to do a physics degree without learning about boolean logic ... in high school maths?)

Answer (score 0):

From Logic, when:

```
 TRUE or FALSE then the result is TRUE,

 FALSE or TRUE then the result is TRUE,

 FALSE or FALSE then the result is FALSE,

 TRUE or TRUE then The result is TRUE
```

so based on your lines of Code

flag = flag or c.islower() it return TRUE when c = "c"
because **FALSE or TRUE then the result is TRUE**

Comment: I was mistaken, I meant when c="c"